# Random Path that covers entire grid

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I have a 3 * 3 grid. I have a 9 letter word that I have to arrange randomly in the grid. The arrangement should be such that there is a valid path in the grid that covers the word sequentially. Valid moves in the grid are: up, down, left, right, diagonal. Cant visit the same element again.

Could you please point me in the right direction? I just want to know what algorithm I should use in this case?

Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier. By random arrangement I meant that the path should not be fixed.

if I have the word BUZZINGLY, a sample path can be:
| B  U  Z |
| N  I  Z |
| G  L  Y |
, so whatever arrangement I choose should be different each time.

Comment: What does `arrange randomly` mean in this context? I can always say that I can assign characters 1,2,3,6,5,4,7,8,9 to fields in square grid, from left to right. And then I always have a proper path (that looks like a snake). But then it's a trivial problem.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier. By random arrangement I meant that the path should not be fixed. 

if I have the word BUZZINGLY, a sample path can be:
| B  U Z |
| N  I   Z |
| G  L  Y|
, so whatever arrangement I choose should be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't very many alternatives and very few if you eliminate symmetric variants. You can just compute them all, store them, and choose one randomly. Then choose a random rotation and mirror operation.

To get you started, this considers the 3 possible starts: corner, center, and mid-edge, and finds all the valid paths.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int b[3][3];

void print(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) printf("%d %d %d\n", b[i][0], b[i][1], b[i][2]);
  printf("\n");
}

void search(int n, int i, int j) {
  if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > 2 || j > 2 || b[i][j]) return;
  b[i][j] = n;
  if (n == 9) print();
  else {
    search(n + 1, i + 1, j);
    search(n + 1, i - 1, j);
    search(n + 1, i, j + 1);
    search(n + 1, i, j - 1);
    search(n + 1, i + 1, j + 1);
    search(n + 1, i - 1, j + 1);
    search(n + 1, i + 1, j - 1);
    search(n + 1, i - 1, j - 1);
  }
  b[i][j] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
  search(1, 0, 0); search(1, 0, 1); search(1, 1, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gene! Thank you for your reply. I am not able to understand your solution but it is probably due to my inability. I will try to understand it. Thank you for replying. :)

Comment: @zeko You can easily work out the variants on paper. There are only 4 that start in a corner, 1 that starts in the middle, and none that starts on a mid-edge. Each can be rotated into 4 positions and/or mirrored. And each path is of course another path backwards.

Comment: @m69 Yeah I know. But where's the fun in that? This is a programming community. Moreover, if he next wants a 5x5, the paper will fill up quickly.

Comment: I was just trying to help zeko picture what your code was doing; it's not a criticism.

Comment: There are, in fact, mid-edge solutions. Consider, for example, `Y L G | I N B | Z Z U`. There are others that are not just rotations or reflections.

Comment: @JimMischel You're right. I overlooked the mention of diagonal moves in the question.

Comment: Thank you Gene for the code! I took me time but I understood it. @m69 your explanation did help me to understand the code. Appreciate it.